# Ionic2 - Labels not appearing for input

Tags: ionic2

I am trying to do something very basic: A label above the input field.
For some reason, this is not working. Any clue ?

```
<ion-header>
   <ion-navbar>
      <ion-title>
         The App
      </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <ion-item no-lines>
     <ion-label stacked>First name</ion-label>
     <ion-input></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
   <ion-item no-lines>
      <ion-label stacked>Last name</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Last Name"></ion-input>
   </ion-item>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer>
  <div (click)="goHome()">Cancel</div>
  <div (click)="save()">Update</div>
</ion-footer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/input/Input/)
 change your code to `<ion-label stacked>` and it should appear on top of your `ion-input`

Comment: No :( Sorry...I just used as example something wrong..even if I place exactly as you said...this will not work...continue to be the same :(

Comment: @MarcoJr if I copy and paste your code into an ionic2 plunkr, the labels are above the input. If you are not seeing this result, something in your css is being annoying and you could debug this using the developer console.

Comment: Ivaro, nevermind...it's was my custom CSS that's was covering the label ! but I really appreciate your help !